# C# Error : Unable to insert record in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Please pardon my knowledge on C# as I am very new to it,I am unable to insert a record in SQL and getting the below error while insert image to SQL.
Error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
byte[] img = ms.ToArray();

if (img == null)
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", null);
}
else
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", img);
}
```

If i select a image and insert it inserts successfully, but if i do not select an image it throws the above error.
Please help!!

Comment: in which line do you have the NullReferenceException ? and why are you so sure your pictureBox1 has an image, and that that image has a RawFormat? did you check that somewhere above in the code?

Comment: `AddWithValue` has to infer the parameter type based on the value passed. Since you are passing `null` it cannot infer the parameter type and throws an error. The best solution is to not use `AddWithValue` and expclicitly type your parameter. More reading: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: The exception message tells it is related to c# code, so that exception may occur here: `pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);` when pictureBox1.Image is null

Comment: @GarethD Yes it should not be used, and yes it throws an error but not a NRE. It is _a parameterized query expects ....._

Comment: @Steve, fair enough, I made an assumption without checking, I stand corrected and using `AddWithValue` is not the cause of the exception being thrown. I would now expect the problem line to be here then: `pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);`, if you don't select an image then `pictureBox.Image` will be null, meaning that you can't call the `Save()` method on the image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try testing that PictureBox1.Image exists before referencing it, like this:

```
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
            byte[] img = ms.ToArray();
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", img);
        }
        else
        {
            com.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 0).Value = DbNull.Value;
        }
```

EDITED to include comment by GarethD

Comment: `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", null);` will still throw an error, it would be better to explicitly declare the parameter type, e.g. `com.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 0).Value = DbNull.Value;` or `com.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 0).Value = img;` (depending on which side of the `if` you are in)

Comment: Thanks, @GarethD. I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Superb this works!! Thank you Everyone..Much Much Appreciated for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
byte[] img = ms.ToArray();
if (img == null)
{
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", null);
}
else
{
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", img);
}
```

To this

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1?.Image?.Save(ms, pictureBox1?.Image?.RawFormat);
byte[] img = ms.ToArray();
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", (object)img ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Error says operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type  byte[]

Comment: Does it work with `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", img);`

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to make a new condition to check is file selected or not.here are code below:

```
if pictureBox1.hasfile == true 
{
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
                    byte[] img = ms.ToArray();

                    if (img == null)
                    {
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", img);
                    }
}
```

because you are not selecting any file thats why it throwing exception on runtime